# Was Throwable class ever abstract?

Tags: java

I often meet people, who think Throwable class is abstract class. Till this day, I thought it was abstract early 9 Java, when I'd started learn it, but I red documentation of 8, 7, 6, 5 Java and class Throwable is concrete there. I couldn't find more early documentation and thought, may be anybody tell me here, was Throwable class ever abstract?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The oldest reference I have on the subject is the 1996 first edition Java in a Nutshell: A Desktop Quick Reference for Java Programmers (available [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565921836)) by David Flanagan on page 327

```
public class Throwable extends Object
```

So **no**. Since Java 1.0 it has been a concrete class.